# *ngIf and local template variables

Tags: angular, interpolation

Could someone please explain what's behind the following behavior?

Say we have an Angular 2 component that has a `_model` object. Then in the template we have this:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" required [(ngModel)]="_model.firstName" ngControl="test2"  #myInput >
    <br>Class: {{myInput?.className}}
</form>
```

The `_model` is available from the beginning being created from scratch in `ngOnInit()`. The input field is properly populated with the `_model.firstName` variable and the line:

`<br>Class: {{myInput?.className}}`

correctly renders the following in the template:

`Class: form-control ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-invalid`.

So far so good. What confuses me is that the moment I add `*ngIf` and I change the input field to

```
<input *ngIf="_model" type="text" class="form-control" required [(ngModel)]="_model.firstName" ngControl="test2"  #myInput >
```

The double curly braces interpolation stops working because apparently the local `myInput` variable doesn't get initialized even when nothing else in the code changes, the `_model object` is still created in `onNgInit()` and the input field is still working properly. The only thing that the `{{myInput?.className}}` renders is

`Class:`

Can someone explain what's going on and/or point me to the correct piece of documentation for this?

**EDIT:**

Here's a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/itNRpy5lc9PB837C7HdP?p=preview) that shows the issue in question.

Created bug report https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8087

Comment: is your _model a boolean?

Comment: Just tested it in my application, and I can reproduce your issue. Somehow `#myInput` gets `undefined` after you add `*ngIf`. This feels like an angular2 bug, or someone must come up with a good explanation.

Comment: You can however get the element by using `@ViewChild('myInput') myInputRef : ElementRef;`, and `Class: {{myInputRef?.nativeElement?.className}}`, but that does not feel like an appropriate approach

Comment: I'll file a bug with the Angular2 guys - they'll know if that's expected behavior or an issue. Meanwhile I've updated the original post with a plunker.

Comment: @RVP try long form of `ngIf` directive, surround `input` with `<template [ngIf]="_model">  ... </template>` tag.

Comment: Thanks @tchelidze but that does not seem to work either.

Comment: [this is interesting](http://plnkr.co/edit/q9iAE1FmjfuLCke93wYu?p=preview), it doesn't work but still interesting

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer let's say we use `ngFor` directive instead of `ngIf`, naming an element and using that names outside of `ngFor` context will not makes sense (*since there will be potentially more that one element with that name*). same goes here, Consider [following](http://plnkr.co/edit/Rvc61V?p=preview), element's name is available inside structural directive's context, but not outside of it. This makes sense, since Angular can't know whether specific directive will repeat his template or not.

Comment: @tchelidze Sounds like an explanation

Answer (score 36, accepted):

> We can reference a local template variable on the same element, on a sibling element, or on any child elements. -- [ref](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#local-vars)

*ngIf becomes/expands to

```
<template [ngIf]="_model">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" required [(ngModel)]="_model.firstName"
     ngControl="test1" #myInput>
</template>
```

So local template variable `#myInput` can only be referenced inside the template block (i.e., sibling and/or child elements).  Hence you would have to put any HTML that wants to reference the local template variable inside the template:

```
<template [ngIf]="_model">
   <input type="text" class="form-control" required [(ngModel)]="_model.firstName"
    ngControl="test1"  #myInput >
   <br>Class (this works): {{myInput?.className}}
</template>
```

<kbd>[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/2XW2EM5AvQzeqWTpS11v?p=preview)</kbd>

---

If you need to show something outside the template block related to the input, use `@ViewChildren('myInput') list:QueryList<ElementRef>` and then subscribe to changes:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
   this.list.changes.subscribe( newList =>
      console.log('new list size:', newList.length)
   )
}
```

See more QueryList methods in the [API doc](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/QueryList-class.html).