# #elmentRef remains undefined when used with *ngIf in angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-template

In angular 2 when **#elementReference** is used with ***ngIf** the reference to the element remains `undefined` even after ***ngIf** expression evaluates to `true`. In following example the `input's` value will not be shown.

```
<input *ngIf="true" type="text" #myRef (input)="a = 'b';" class="form-control input-lg">
<pre> {{ myRef?.value }} </pre>
```

But however following will work (surprised me).

```
<div *ngIf="true">
          <input type="text" #myRef (input)="a = 'b';" class="form-control input-lg">
          <pre> {{ myRef?.value }} </pre>
      </div>
```

My question is how do I get the #reference to the element from anywhere in the template when used with *ngIf like directives.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular2, \*ngIf and local template variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36642487/angular2-ngif-and-local-template-variables)

Answer (score 1):

[The documentation](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/core/index/ElementRef-class.html) recommends against using elementRef in situations where data binding is possible:

> Use this API as the last resort when direct access to DOM is needed. Use templating and data-binding provided by Angular instead.

Solution using data-binding:

```
<input *ngIf="true" type="text" [(ngModel)]="myModel" (input)="a = 'b';" class="form-control input-lg">
<pre> {{ myModel }} </pre>
```

Comment: `elementRef` is not being used here. `#myRef` is a [template reference variable](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#ref-vars) which is fine to use. Template reference variables would fall under 'templating' in the docs you quoted.

Comment: See this question for the explanation of why *ngIf and #refs don't work on the same element: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36642487/angular2-ngif-and-local-template-variables#36651625

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour would be caused by the fact that

```
<div *ngIf="show"></div>
```

is [syntactic sugar](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#expanding-ngif-) for

```
<template [ngIf]="show">
  <div></div>
</template>
```

[Template reference variables](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#referencing-a-template-reference-variable) can only be used

> on the same element, on a sibling element, or on any child elements.

Your example looks like this desugared:

```
<template [ngIf]="true">
  <input type="text" #myRef (input)="a = 'b';" class="form-control input-lg">
</template
<pre> {{ myRef?.value }} </pre>
```

As you can see, the reference variable `#myRef` is not a sibling of the `pre` element that tries to use it and so it won't work.