# Template Element Reference isn't updated when ngIf state changes

Tags: angular

Here is the example I am talking about: http://plnkr.co/edit/VxRH7W?p=preview

Basically, we have a template element reference `#theContainer` which is used in another element (`h1`).

There's a condition (`*ngIf="theCondition"`) for the container to render or not (I don't want to use `hidden`).

When the condition changes, the template element reference isn't updated, neither `ngOnChanges` is called.

It looks a bug in Angular to me, am I right?

*You can find more information in the file `src/app.ts`

Comment: Might be http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36642487/angular2-ngif-and-local-template-variables

Comment: No, it's not. I just filed an issue in Angular's Github (with more details): https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11065

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According this https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#star-template DOM will look like this after **expanding *ngIf**

```
<div>
  <h2>Here is it: {{myContainer || 'not assigned yet'}}</h2>

  <button type="button" (click)="theCondition = !theCondition">Switch to {{!theCondition}}</button>

  <template [ngIf]="theCondition">
    <div #myContainer *ngIf="theCondition">
      <p>I see the container's content!</p>

      <p>You should see the container reference in the header.</p>

      <p>Look at src/app.ts</p>
    </div>
  </template>
</div>
```

Now we have problem because

> We can reference a template reference variable on the same element, on a sibling element, or on any child elements.

You can find it here https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#ref-vars

Please correct me if I am wrong. Still really noob with Angular.

Thanks Günter Zöchbauer to learn this.