# Angular2 Can't bind component using exportAs

Tags: angular, typescript

I have the following code (Angular2 rc.5) :

app.html

```
<div>
  <myComp #compo-binding="my-comp" *ngIf="someCondition"></myComp>
  {{ compo-binding.test }}
</div>
```

The myComp's html is injected correctly, however `compo-binding.test` is generating an error saying that test doesn't exist on undefined

myComp.component.ts

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core"

@Component({
    selector: "myComp",
    exportAs: "my-comp",
    templateUrl: "./myComp.html"
})
export class MyComp{
    test: boolean = true
}
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong with the `exportAs` ?

Comment: And the error happens with the exact code above, or is there some `*ngIf` involved in your real code? Have you tried to not use `-` in the template variable name? Seeing the exact error message would be great.

Comment: There is indeed an *ngIf on myComp. I didn't specify it as I didn't think it would matter

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36642487/angular2-ngif-and-local-template-variables

Comment: That's perfectly correct, thanks sir !

Comment: Can we make it a duplicate of the linked question?

Comment: Yes definitely.