# #varName is returning me undefined in angular2

Tags: angular

I am trying to access a value of my input field.
here is sample code

```
<div>
    Test <input #test1 type="number" [value]='somevalue'/>
</div>
<div *ngIf='some-condition'>
    Test <input #test2 type="number" [value]='somevalue'/>
</div>

<span (click)="testData(test1,test2)">test<span>
```

Angular Code

```
testData(testa,testD)
{
    Console.log(testa);
    Console.log(testD);
}
```

In above code, first div is working fine, but I am trying to do same thing in second div. It is giving me undefined value. I know something is missed.

if condition is false than it gives me undefined is fine, but when condition true is than also giving me undefined value.

Comment: I guess this is what you want http://stackoverflow.com/a/36651625/2435473

Comment: Also you can take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39366981/angular-2-viewchild-in-ngif

Answer (score 0):

try this:-

```
<div>
    Test <input #test1 type="number" [value]='somevalue' (click)="testData(test1.value)"/>
</div>
<div *ngIf='some-condition'>
    Test <input #test2 type="number" [value]='somevalue' (click)="testData(test2.value)"/>
</div>

testData(testD)
{
    Console.log(testD);
}
```

working example here with `variable.value`
<kbd>[Working Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/dTEZZKN9FsK15QPgb6gP?p=preview)</kbd>

Comment: I think the problem here is that the actual ElementRef object (test2) is undefined due to being recreated after the condition becomes true. I don't think your answer would help here.

Comment: But the point is `test2` is undefined in OP case, whats wrong happen with him?

Comment: opps sorry my fault misunderstood the question i think @PankajParkar

Comment: just give me a mintue ill post the exact answer @PankajParkar

Comment: yes @pradeep Jain pankaj is right..when I put *ngIf than only its give me undeffined even if I will put *ngIf='true'.

Comment: Hello @PardeepJain I have update my question Actually problem is occurs when I try this. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You can use [hidden] instead of *ngIf. 
Variable declared inside *ngIf cannot be used outside it.

```
<div>
Test <input #test1 type="number" [value]='somevalue'/>
</div>
<div [hidden] ='somecondition'>
Test <input #test2 type="number" [value]='somevalue'/>
</div>

<span (click)="testData(test1.value,test2.value)">test</span>
```

Please refer this link for more clarification https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6179

Comment: Hidden doesn't have the same effect as *ngIf. NgIf removes the element completly from the dom, while hidden just uses css to hide an element.