# Cannot read property 'value' of undefined in Angular2 Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I am building an Angular2 app and trying to get rid of a div on click through `*ngIf`

Here's my view:

```
<router-outlet>

<div class="releasesMenu" *ngIf="detailedInfo">
  <h1>Releases</h1>
  <div class="search">
    <input type="text" #search (keyup)="0" placeholder="Find release by its name, song or year">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="releasesOutlet container">
        <div class="row releasesBlock">
           <div *ngFor="let release of (releases| searchFilter: search.value )" class="releaseRender" (click)="onSelect(release)">
              <div class="releaseRenderWrap" *ngIf="!selectedRelease">
            <span>Something interesting...</span>
          </div>
       </div>

        <div class="releaseDetails" *ngIf="selectedRelease">
          <div class="releaseDetailsWrap">
                <span>Some details...</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</router-outlet>
```

Here's my controller:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { SearchFilter } from './../search-filter.pipe';
import { ReleasesService } from '../releases/releases.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'releases-component',
  providers: [ReleasesService],
  templateUrl: './app/releases/releases.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app/releases/releases.component.css','./css/grid.css']
})

export class ReleasesComponent implements OnInit { 
  releases: any = [];
  release: any;
  selectedRelease: any;
  private detailedInfo: boolean;

  onSelect(release){
    this.detailedInfo = false;
    this.selectedRelease = release;
    console.log(release)
    }

  constructor(private releasesService: ReleasesService){ }

  ngOnInit(){
    this.releasesService.getReleases()
    .subscribe(data => this.releases = data);
  }

}
```

What I want is to remove / hide my `.releasesMenu` block on `(click)="onSelect(release)`. But I am getting the error:
**Cannot read property 'value' of undefined**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because `#search` is inside an `*ngIf`

Add this to your components class

```
@ViewChild('search')search:ElementRef;
```

and change `*ngFor` to

```
*ngFor="let release of (releases| searchFilter: search?.nativeElement?.value )"
```

See also [Angular2, *ngIf and local template variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36642487/angular2-ngif-and-local-template-variables/36651625#36651625)