# Angular how to get button element on form submit

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a page with multiple forms on it. Each form has a number of buttons on it. I would like to implement a loading spinner on buttons after they are pressed. When I use a normal click event I can pass in the button:

HTML

```
<button #cancelButton class="button-with-icon" type="button" *ngIf="hasCancel" mat-raised-button color="warn" [disabled]="isLoading" (click)="clickEvent(cancelButton)">
    <mat-spinner *ngIf="isLoading" style="display: inline-block;" diameter="24"></mat-spinner>
    Cancel
</button>
```

TS

```
clickEvent(button: MatButton) {
    console.log(button);
}
```

In this case the button element gets passed through and you can access it in order to add a loading class to the button.

However, if you try the same thing using a submit button it comes through as `undefined`:

HTML

```
<form (ngSubmit)="save(saveButton)">
    <button #saveButton class="button-with-icon" type="submit" *ngIf="hasSave" mat-raised-button color="primary" [disabled]="isLoading">
        <mat-spinner *ngIf="isLoading" style="display: inline-block;" diameter="24"></mat-spinner>
        Save
    </button>
</form>
```

TS

```
save(button: MatButton) {
    console.log(button);
}
```

In this case button is `undefined` because the `*ngIf` on the button blocks it from the scope of the form. I could remove the `*ngIf` and just hide the button, but this leaves the button on the DOM and I do not want to do that.

Here is a stack blitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zh7jcw-mrqaok?file=app%2Fform-field-overview-example.html

I have tried adding an additional click event to the save button to set the button to loading but the click event fires first and set the button to disabled before blocking the submit event from being called.

Ive looked through the submit event but cant see anything that links back to the button that was clicked.

Any suggestions?

Comment: First of all... why would you need to manipulate the dom like that (adding loading), any special reason?

Comment: The save and cancel functions will call asynchronously to a web server. I want to disable the buttons and show a spinning icon on the button while the async call is being handled. I am making a dynamic form component. That can have multiple forms and multiple buttons on each form. So keeping track of which button is loading through a fixed variable seemed less efficient than just adding a `loading` class to the dom of the button.

Comment: Ok, I get it. Some people just do this when they simply a boolean flag would suffice, but I see your reason in this case well :)

Comment: @Curtis I'm not sure what your efficiency concern is here. The point is that Angular does this for by storing the state in the component instead of the DOM. It's less code and it is not less performant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using the `ngSubmit` event handler on the form use a `click` event handler on the save button. Leave the type as `submit` so that it still works when the user uses the `Enter` key on an input control to submit the form.

```
<form #formElement="ngForm">
    ...
    <button #saveButton (click)="save(saveButton, formElement)" type="submit" ...>
        <mat-spinner ...></mat-spinner>
        Save
    </button>
</form>
```

You can also avoid needing to add the `loading` class to the DOM by using an object to keep track of which button is in the loading state. Working example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zh7jcw-tnbyg4?file=app%2Fform-field-overview-example.ts). This also allows you to have many buttons without having to create a fixed variable for each button.

```js
class FormFieldOverviewExample {
  
  hasCancel = true;
  hasSave = true;
  isLoading = {};

  saveEvent(event, buttonName, form) {
    console.log(buttonName);
    if(form.valid) {
      this.isLoading[buttonName]=true;
      // ...
    } else {
      this.isLoading[buttonName]=false;
      console.warn("Form not submitted because it contains errors");
    }
  }

  clickEvent(event, buttonName) {
    console.log(buttonName);
    this.isLoading[buttonName]=true;
    // ...
  }
}
```

```css
form { display: none; }
```

```html
<form #formElement="ngForm">

  ...

  <button (click)="clickEvent($event, 'cancelButton')" [disabled]="isLoading['cancelButton']" *ngIf="hasCancel" type="button" ...>
    <mat-spinner *ngIf="isLoading['cancelButton']" ...></mat-spinner>
    Cancel
  </button> 
  
  <br><br>
  
  <button (click)="saveEvent($event, 'saveButton', formElement)"  [disabled]="isLoading['saveButton']" *ngIf="hasSave" type="submit" ...>
    <mat-spinner *ngIf="isLoading['saveButton']" ...></mat-spinner>
    Save
  </button>
</form>
```

Comment: What is the problem with the OP's approach? Suggesting a workaround without understanding the problem is problematic.

Comment: Also, this wouldn't work if user submitted the form using enter... I know, not the case here, but you should always handle the submit for good measure

Comment: I tried this before, I seem to recall there being issues with submit. But I just tried it again... and I cant seem to find any issues, so maybe last time I just had a typo or bug or something. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zh7jcw-mwklob?file=app/form-field-overview-example.ts .. works with submitting the form through the Enter button too... Doesnt answer the question, but it looks to solve my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

**Update** I understand your particular issue now. The problem is the `*ngIf`  on the button. It's breaking the reference. Change it to `[hidden]` and it should work. Here's an updated StackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zh7jcw-pcuuyv

As for why it happen, I think this describes the problem pretty well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36651625/64279

Original answer:

I wouldn't even pass it in. Just add this in your class:

```
 @ViewChild('saveButton') button;
```

Then you can reference it in your save method:

```
save() {
    console.log(this.saveButton);
}
```

But I will also add that calling function from interpolation is not a good idea as it can cause performance issues. Rather, you should subscribe to an event which sets a property, then reference that property in your view. That way, the function is only called when the event fires instead of every rendering of the page.

Comment: The issue with this is that there can be a number of save buttons on the component. Because there can be a number of forms on the page. Even if I used ViewChildren, I would still need to know which form was being submitted to find out which save button was being clicked.

Comment: Yet another "try this other approach even though your current approach should work".

Comment: @Curtis, see my update. I tested it on you StackBlitz and it works.

Comment: @JuanMendes, I can't wait to see what you contribute.

Comment: @adam0101 nice investigation in Update

Comment: @adam0101 I'm not sure what the problem is and I prefer not to spout random suggestions to patch up a problem I don't understand. At the very least, your answer should explain that the OP's approach should work, but they could try this workaround... Don't claim this is an answer to a problem, as for your update, the OP's example has the button visible and it doesn't work.

Comment: @JuanMendes maybe you should test it and see. It's not the value of the `*ngIf` that's breaking it, its the existence of the `*ngIf`.

Comment: Good catch, why didn't I see that! But some explanation to why this is would be useful and worth a thumbs up ;)

Comment: Of course I tested it :)  I didn't realize just the presence of `ngIf` would cause the problem. It fails even with `*ngIf=true`, seems to be angular bug. Now, why doesn't the problem happen on the other button? I still don't feel like the actual problem has been discovered.

Comment: it's not a bug ;) This is something angular does under the hood, still waiting that @adam0101 would explain why this is.

Comment: because in cancel button the `*ngIf` and event handling `clickEvent ` is in same node `<button>`. But in second case event handler `save` is in outer node `<form>` (not in `<button>` which has `*ngIf`) - `angular way ;)`

Comment: @AJT_82, I added a link to an explanation.

Comment: Yes, I already figured out the `*ngIf` was breaking the reference. But I didnt want to just hide the button. Cause then the user can edit the code and turn the button back on. So I was looking for another solution.

Answer (score 2):

This actually has nothing to do with the submit function, but all to do with angular and structural directives. When you apply a structural directive (`ngFor`, `ngIf`...) what angular does under the hood is to create a `ng-template` node. What this means, that template reference variables that are defined in the scope of the structural directive is **only** available in that node.

So what you have here:

```
<button #saveButton *ngIf="hasSave">
  Save
</button>
```

means that `saveButton` template reference is only available inside that `ng-template` which is created for the button, and therefore not available in the submit function.

What we have here:

```
<button #cancelButton *ngIf="hasCancel" (click)="clickEvent(cancelButton)">
  Cancel
</button>
```

is that the click event is on the button, so `cancelButton` template reference variable is available for that event.

Using `hidden` instead of `ngIf` like suggested in other answer, solves this issue, since we just.. well, hide the element.

Comment: * only available in that node _and child nodes, but not parent nodes_

Comment: I haven't seen this documented... Do you have a link? Here's an example showing that adding `*ngIf` makes the the element reference not available outside of that node:. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zh7jcw-u3eakq

Comment: Sorry for not making it clear in my original post, but I did know of this work around. I just didn't want to have the element hidden on the DOM, I was looking for a solution where the `*ngIf` is still there.

Comment: @Curtis I explained why this is, you need to do some kind another workaround, with ngIf, for example with `hidden`, but as your code sits in your question... structural directives just does this, without you having any control over it. But glad that you found a solution suitable for you :)

Comment: @JuanMendes Yes, this is just how angular and structural directives work. Documentation is surprisingly hard to find, when I looked for it... here's one post though that I found: https://weblogs.thinktecture.com/thomas/2017/05/use-angular-template-reference-variables-anywhere-in-the-template-not.html

Answer (score 2):

**tl;dr** Here is my solution in action: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zh7jcw-ythpdb

---

Edit: As I just noticed, @AJT_82 explains OP's original problem with the reference element very well. So I now removed my earlier answer.

---

However I would suggest the following solution that would fit much better in terms of **separation of concerns** and **doing things in angular way**, that is by introducing two new members `cancelActive` and `submitActive`, you will be able to handle the different states of the form more flexibly.

Here you can see it in action: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zh7jcw-ythpdb

```
export class FormFieldOverviewExample {
  cancelActive = false;
  submitActive = false;

  // this is for submit event
  saveEvent(event: Event) {
    // additional logic can be added
    // if(!this.cancelActive) return;

    this.submitActive = true;
    this.cancelActive = false;
  }

  // this is for cancel event
  cancelEvent(event: Event) {
    // additional logic can be added
    // if(!this.submitActive) return;

    this.submitActive = true;
    this.cancelActive = false;
  }

}
```

```html
<form (ngSubmit)="saveEvent($event)">
  <button  class="button-with-icon"  type="button"  *ngIf="hasCancel"  mat-raised-button color="warn"  [disabled]="cancelActive"  (click)="cancelEvent($event)">
    <mat-spinner *ngIf="cancelActive" class="spinner" diameter="15"></mat-spinner>
    Cancel
  </button>
  <br><br>
  <button class="button-with-icon" type="submit" *ngIf="hasSave" mat-raised-button color="primary" [disabled]="submitActive">
    <mat-spinner *ngIf="submitActive" class="spinner" diameter="15"></mat-spinner>
    Save
  </button>
</form>
```

This way you would also have more playground, such as:

```
<button type="submit" [disabled]="submitActive || cancelActive">...</button>
```

You can simply disable the `submit` button without showing the loading animation for it, if you want to do it for some reason...

Further, suppose you have an `<input type="text" />` element in your form. User switches to that element (via click or tab press) and after he is done with editing he presses the Enter key, in this case, the form is also submitted automatically by the browser; so this would make things even more complicated in your existing code structure.

Comment: As mentioned by [@AJT_82](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55909882/227299) This scoping of the element reference only occurs within structural directives. You should update the answer to include that information. Here's an example where you can get a sibling's reference if it does not contain an `*ngIf` I haven't seen this documented... Do you have a link? Here's an example showing that adding `*ngIf` makes the the element reference not available outside of that node:. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zh7jcw-u3eakq

Comment: This requires fixed variables for each button. Not what I'm after. While my demo did have fixed variables: `hasCancel` and `hasSave`. In reality I dont have these variables in my code. The component would dynamically make as many buttons and forms as the API tells it to.

Comment: @Curtis Thanks for the info. Since this spec you mention is part of your problem and seems important, I'ld have included it in the question description, so that the others would be aware of it. I'm glad you solved your problem though.

Comment: Hey @JuanMendes, thanks for the hint! To be honest, I was quite lazy yesterday and didn't read any of those answers. Instead I wrote my own. Anyway, I just updated my answer accordingly. To your question: I have no link, I just knew it based on my experiences. :)

Comment: @JuanMendes This might be slightly easier to read, but it has an overhead cost and isn't flexible.

Comment: @Kenan Güler I didn't include that in my post because it wasn't relevant to my question. Yes it would help others suggest different workarounds that might help me in my specific use case but workarounds usually only work in a very limited scope. They wouldn't necessarily work in all use cases the might require the reference to the button.

Answer (score 1):

FOr your case, you should not pass the element to the function and then manipulate the class on it but rather simply maintain a variable for loading state. In your component, initialize it as

```
loading: boolean = false;
```

And in your template, bind this class as

```
[class.loading]="loading"
```

In your method, set this property initially to true and then to false once the async call is complete. Similary use the same variable to set disabled attribute as

```
[disabled]="loading"
```

Comment: I am making a dynamic component that can have multiple forms and multiple buttons on each form. So keeping track of which button is loading through a fixed variable seemed less efficient than just adding a loading class to the dom of the button. If I did it this way, I would need to make a matrix of loading variables and have to keep traversing that matrix to check each buttons state.